# Changing unix file permission from terminal

Tags: unix, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I just copied all my files from one Ubuntu server to another, and everything works fine, except that Apache returns a "ERROR 500 - Internal Server Error!" on image files that on the old server was uploaded by the user himself through a PHP script.

I log in to the server through the terminal with ssh as root.

Checking the file permissions using the "ls -l" command through terminal shows the following:

Example of a file that Apache does display correctly:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41447 Jan  6 03:27 layout1.png

Example of a file that returns 500 error:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   67736 Jan  6 03:28 5142f83f837ad.jpg

So the question is: **How can I force "-rw-r--r--" to a file?**

And to make life easier: How can I force this permission to all files in a directory, including its subdirectories?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an operating system question, not programming. It is more appropriate for [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [su] instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
chmod 644 <filename>
```

or

```
chmod -R 644 <directory>
```

will do what you want.

Note that if the user you want to use to write isn't the owner, this won't work the way you expect. "rw-r--r--" means "writeable by the owner, readable by everyone else".

You may need to set the owner correctly (using chown) to get the behaviour you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the chmod command. Use `chmod 644 -R *` in the directory you want to recursively change permissions.